# remove class name using pure js

Tags: javascript, css

```
  <div class="wrap">
</div>
```

my css

```
.wrap{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

should I do like this in js?

```
document.getElementById("whatever").className = "";
```

where to get the id in this case? since I use .wrap not #wrap.

Comment: There's a `getElementsByClassName` function as well. More from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0].className = "";//If you have only one .whatever

Comment: There seems to be a big gap between your title and your actual question. Are you asking how to remove a class from an element, or are you asking how to get an element via class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the DOM function `getElementByClassName()`.

For example, if you run var `x = document.getElementByClassName('wrap')` in your case, `x` will be a list of all dom elements which have the class `'wrap'` .

source: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but to give you an easy example, have a look at this:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('wrap');

for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {

  divs[i].addEventListener('click', removemyclass);

}

function removemyclass () {
  
  this.className = '';
  
  }
```

```css
.wrap {

  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
```

This will find the one ( this ) element you are clicking on and remove its class Name, so that it doesn't have a border anymore, but you can still find it in your console as an element in the DOM